# Building an RTSP streaming server from processed frames in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, gstreamer, rtsp

I have to process frames from a distant camera using OpenCV.

I need to stream the processed frames to be accessible over network as a live video.

How to make the processed frames (cv::Mat objects) be passed to the RTSP streaming server in real time?